# How to create a database of following structure in pouchdb

Tags: nosql, pouchdb

I want to create a database in pouchdb that has following structure

/db
--mycontacts
------|contact1
------|contact2
------|contact3
------|contact4

Here `mycontacts` is a node in database `db` which contains all the contacts.

I want to know how I can create a node in db and push contacts in to this node as user add new contact.

Comment: PouchDB databases (an indeed most or all NoSQL databases) have no structure. That's why they're called "schemaless".  You just put whatever documents you want into them.

Answer (score 1):

Using PouchDB is pretty simple:

```
var db = new PouchDB('mycontacts'); // Create mycontacts db

// Write contact1
db.put({
  _id: 'oscar@gmail.com',
  name: 'Oscar',
  Phone: '0987665544'
});
```

EDIT:

Ultimately it's json all the way. If you want to store your contacts as an array, all you need to do is:

```
var db = new PouchDB('mydatabaser'); // Create mycontacts db

db.put({
  _id: '...',
  mycontacts: [{
    name: 'Oscar',
    phone: '0987665544'}, {
    name: 'Bob',
    phone: '0765432190'}, {
    name: 'Eric',
    phone: '0855664432'}
 ]
});
```

A word of warning though -- the last structure is likely less efficient than the first, as every time you add a new contact you will need to mutate an existing document rather than adding a new one. Immutable structures are much better suited to the CouchDB/PouchDB/Cloudant family of databases.

Comment: Here "mycontacts" is a database but what I want is "mycontacts" to be a an item in the database that contains an array of contacts

Comment: Edited my answer to expand it following your comment.

Comment: so, every time I want to add new contact , I have to fetch the contact array and push this new object and put it into database again?

Comment: Yes -- hence my comment that it's a bad approach. Add separate documents one for each contact instead as I originally proposed.